# R - Unable to store large binary values

Tags: r

I have a large binary value:

```
   longbinary<-10110101110000111
```

But the value getting stored in longbinary is  10110101110000112.

How can i get the correct value without any changes in the end. I tried using the int64 package but it is not available for version 3.1.2 or 3.2.

Is there a way out ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I'm just starting to play around with R, I suspect that when you are doing

```
longbinary<-10110101110000111
```

you are effective saving a decimal number worth 10e+17. So that is near the maximum resolution of numeric() in R, and surely above integer(). I think you should save it's decimal value, and just convert it to print in binary if necessary.

```
10110101110000111 binary = 93063 decimal = strtoi("10110101110000111", 2)
```

The inverse (integer to binary string) is in R.utils: `intToBin`

```
intToBin(93063) gives the string "10110101110000111":

> library(R.utils)
> intToBin(93063)
[1] "10110101110000111"
```

Comment: how do i covert it to print in binary? Even if i convert , the last digit will still get changed right ?

Comment: Edited the answer. No - the last bit will be right, because the number you're saving is 93063, which is a normal integer value. You're only converting it to string to show it.